# Remove objects connected to right and bottom borders

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to remove white objects connected to right and bottom borders. I tried `imclearborder` but don't know how to exclude objects connected to top and left borders.

[image: My Image]

Comment: is your object black or white? Provide more informaiton please.
Read [ask]

Comment: What have you done to the image so far? Do you have the connected components? Have you tried using `imfill`? There seem to be some little white bubbles over on the right edge, do you need those removed too? If so, how have you tried to join them with the larger white blob on the right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `imclearborder`, but you should pad the left and top edges of the image first so that they are not touching the border (and therefore, are not cleared).

**Code:**

```
I = imread('gQKc8.png');         %// your image

J = zeros(size(I)+1,'uint8');    %// initialize a padded matrix
J = J(:,:,1:3);                  %// (we didn't need to pad the third-dimension)
J(2:end,2:end,:) = I;            %// assign I to the lower-right of J

C = imclearborder(J,4);          %// now run imclearborder, using connectedness option 4
C = C(2:end,2:end,:);            %// remove the padding
```

Connectedness option 4 in `imclearborder` just tells the function to only check the four two-d neighboring pixels. See [`imclearborder`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imclearborder.html) documentation for more info.

**Plotting the result:**

```
%// for comparison:
B=imclearborder(I,4);             %// imclearborder on the original
subplot(221); imshow(I);
subplot(222); imshow(B);
subplot(223); imshow(J);
subplot(224); imshow(C);
```

from left to right, top to bottom:

1. original image
2. using `imclearborder` directly on original
3. padded image
4. desired result, using `imclearborder` on padded image

[image: result compared to original]

**Note:** as @beaker commented, since the two little white blobs on the right are **not** connected to the border, they are not cleared. If you also want to remove them you'll need to define more precisely what decides whether or not a blob should be cleared.